# Django+Cython Deployment with Gunicorn

Tags: django, cython, gunicorn

I have a Django application and I don't want to provide access my source code. As a result of my research, I used the [Djcompiler](https://github.com/abdoohossamm/djcompiler#djcompiler) library, which basically uses Cython. As a result, I converted the project into .so modules.

When I run this converted project with the `python3 manage.py runserver` command, the project runs smoothly. However, when I run the project for production via Gunicorn with the `gunicorn tracking.wsgi.python-39-darwin:application --bind0.0.0.0:7005`command, I get the following errors:

> 1. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accounts.urls'
> 2. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'log.models'

How can I successfully implement this Cython converted project to .so modules with Gunicorn?

Comment: Cython is not designed as an obfuscator/code security tool. If it seems to work as one it's accidental. It's open-source so you're welcome to use it as you want but it's worth emphasising that no effort has gone into keeping your code hidden.